# How to read XML file to a Dictionary<String,List<String>> with empty strings for null elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq, dictionary

I'm having an xml file like:

```
<root>
  <RowDetails RowName="A" ColumnSize="1">
    <ColumnDetails ColumnName="A1" />
  </RowDetails>
  <RowDetails RowName="B" ColumnSize="2">
    <ColumnDetails ColumnName="B1" />
    <ColumnDetails ColumnName="B2" />
  </RowDetails>
  <RowDetails RowName="C" ColumnSize="3">
    <ColumnDetails ColumnName="C1" />
    <ColumnDetails ColumnName="C2" />
    <ColumnDetails ColumnName="C3" />
  </RowDetails>
</root>
```

and a Dictionary like :

```
Dictionary<String, List<String>>MyDict = new Dictioanary<String, List<String>>();
```

and i'm reading the XML file to `MyDict` is like:

```
XDocument XDoc = XDocument.Load(Application.StartupPath + @"\foo.xml");
MyDict = XDoc.Descendants("RowDetails").ToDictionary(X => X.Attribute("RowName").Value, 
                                                     X => X.Descendants("ColumnDetails")
                                                           .Select(Y => Y.Attribute("ColumnName").Value).ToList());
```

Now the Dictionary will contain:

```
"A"           { "A1" }
"B"           { "B1", "B2" }
"C"           { "C1", "C2", "C3" }
```

but my problem is that I need all the list with same count. Empty string should be added for null entry, so the expected result is:

```
"A"           { "A1", "", "" }
"B"           { "B1", "B2", "" }
"C"           { "C1", "C2", "C3" }
```

How can I modify my LINQ query?

Please help me to do this using LINQ.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you would like this to be done as a post-processing step after `MyDict` is created, the basic idea would be:

1. Find out what the size of each list *should* be (based on the count of the biggest list).
2. Pad each list with empty strings as required to bring it up to the right size.

---

```
// The required size is the count of the biggest list
var sizeRequired = MyDict.Values.Max(l => l.Count);

// Pad each list as necessary
foreach (var list in MyDict.Values)
    list.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(string.Empty, sizeRequired - list.Count));
```

Here's a way to return a new Dictionary with the required characteristics *without* mutating the original collection:

```
 // The required size is the count of the biggest list
var sizeRequired = MyDict.Values.Max(l => l.Count);

// Each string key should map to a key in the new dictionary
// Each List<string> value should map to a new list, padded as necessary.
var paddedDict = MyDict.ToDictionary
  (
     kvp => kvp.Key,
     kvp => kvp.Value
               .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(string.Empty, sizeRequired - kvp.Value.Count))
               .ToList()
  );
```

Comment: (+1) . Could you please suggest a method in LINQ( instead of `Foreach`)

Comment: yes ...Now i'm using like `int i = XDoc.Descendants("RowDetails").Max(X => Convert.ToInt32(X.Attribute("ColumnSize").Value));`

Comment: `MyDict = XDoc.Descendants("RowDetails") .ToDictionary(X => X.Attribute("RowName").Value, X => X.Descendants("ColumnDetails") .Select(Y => Y.Attribute("ColumnName").Value) .ToList() ).ToDictionary(X => X.Key, X => X.Value.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(String.Empty, i - X.Value.Count)).ToList());`

Comment: Any idea to make this Query simple

Comment: I don't think so. I would split it up though; it does appear very unreadable.

Comment: @ Ani , i've one more doubt regarding this. please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084524/how-to-add-data-from-a-dictionary-to-a-list-view-control-in-c-winfroms

Answer (score 2):

You could create an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>` to pad to a minimum size, inline:

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> PadIfFewerThan<TSource>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> items,
        int size, TSource padValue = default(TSource))
    {
        int count = 0;

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            ++count;
            yield return item;
        }

        foreach (var index in Enumerable.Range(count, size - count))
            yield return padValue;
    }
}
```

Your resulting code will look like:

```
var dictionary = doc.Descendants("RowDetails")
    .ToDictionary(
        x => x.Attribute("RowName").Value,
        x => x.Descendants("ColumnDetails")
            .Select(y => y.Attribute("ColumnName").Value)
            .PadIfFewerThan(3, "")
        );

foreach (var entry in dictionary)
    Console.WriteLine(@"""{0}""    {{""{1}""}}",
        entry.Key,
        string.Join(@""",""", entry.Value)
        );
```

> "A" {"A1","",""}
>   
> "B" {"B1","B2",""}
>   
> "C" {"C1","C2","C3"}

If you must have a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, rather than the `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>` that is returned here, simply put your `.ToList()` back in the mix:

```
var dictionary = doc.Descendants("RowDetails")
    .ToDictionary(
        x => x.Attribute("RowName").Value,
        x => x.Descendants("ColumnDetails")
            .Select(y => y.Attribute("ColumnName").Value)
            .PadIfFewerThan(3)
            .ToList()
        );
```

Comment: Another option (which I'd personally take if I could) is to get rid of this custom XML serialization, and use the default XML serializer where at all possible.  I find XML's "human readability/editability" overrated ;)

Comment: @Pramodh: You get 3 different method overloads here, for the price of implementing one.  I figure if you can make it generic quickly, in a clean (mostly bug free) way, why not :)

Comment: @Pramodh: Had a bug.  My code worked, but the strings were still `null` :)  Fixed that, and boiled it back down to a single extension method, for simplicity's sake.  If you're interested in the more generalized extension methods, check the edit history.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if there is a way "in LINQ" ... I'd probably do what you want to do in C# code as well.

But, where is this requirement coming from?  could it be that the code should be changed there where it expects for all Lists in your dictionary to be of the same size?