# How to add Data from a Dictionary to a List View Control

Tags: c#, linq, listview

(Its a continution fo my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084393/how-to-read-xml-file-to-a-dictionarystring-liststring-with-empty-strings-for/4084407#4084407).
Now i'm having a dictionary

```
Dictionary<String, List<String>>MyDict = new Dictioanary<String, List<String>>();
```

and which contains

```
"A"           { "A1", "", "" } 
"B"           { "B1", "B2", "" } 
"C"           { "C1", "C2", "C3" }
```

i need to add tthis data to a list view
[image]

Here the dictionary key is the Column header and Value is the item in each cell

so finally the `ListView` will be like

[image]

Using nested `for` loop we can do this, but is there any way to do this using LINQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there any way to do this using LINQ.

Possibly, if you torture it beyond breaking point. However, that isn't really where LINQ excels. If your current approach with a loop works, stick with that.

As some asides:

- the ordering of keys in a dictionary is not defied; you should note that (unless you sort explicitly) {"C","A","D","B"} is a perfectly valid key order (regardless of what order you added them)
- you *might* want to consider `ILookup<TKey,TValue>`, which describes a multi-map between a each key and multiple values; the default (`Lookup<TKey,TValue>`) is immutable, but it is easy enough to write a mutable variant.