# XML to String List

Tags: c#, xml

I have some code that I need to put into a string list in C# and I am reading this code from an XML files and the layout of it is something like below...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<accountlist>
    <main>
        <account id="1" special_id="4923959">
            <username>Adam</username>
            <motto>Hello Everyone>
            <money>1004</money>
            <friends>394</friends>
            <rareid>9</rareid>
            <mission>10</mission>
        </account>
    </main>
</accountlist>
```

How can I put each account tag into a string list? from the first < account > to the < / account > tag?

Please do NOT  tell me to go to the link below as it does NOT work!!
[How to read a XML file and write into List<>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619324/how-to-read-a-xml-file-and-write-into-list)

So far I have tried the below code, and the string list just stays empty

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(this._accountsFile);

            List<string> list = doc.Root.Elements("account")
                               .Select(element => element.Value)
                               .ToList();

            this._accounts = list;
```

Comment: What does "not work" entail? You should show the code you have tried

Comment: It doesn't add anything to the list.. the list stays empty.

Comment: I have updated my question to my code I have tried.

Comment: Is it just your example that your `<motto>Hello Everyone>` element is broken?

Comment: There is no such thing as InnerXml in Value

Comment: Yes, this is just an example.

Comment: You are not making any sence.

Comment: `account` isn't an element of root though, have you tried selecting the `main` element first then getting the `account` elements of that?

Comment: [Nevermind](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rwkKbw), sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work on your example (but you need to close this tag `<motto>Hello Everyone>`

```
      public List<string> GetAccountsAsXmlList(string filePath)
      {
        XmlDocument x = new XmlDocument();

        x.Load(filePath);
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        XmlNode currentNode;
        foreach (var accountNode in x.LastChild.FirstChild.ChildNodes)
        {
            currentNode = accountNode  as XmlNode;
            result.Add(currentNode.InnerXml);
        }
          return result;
      }
```

---

**EDIT** as an answer to your question:

> Is there a way I can get the id and specal_id in a seperate string?

you can use `currentNode.Attributes["YourAttributeName"].Value,` to get the values.

---

assume you have class Account :

```
class Account
    {
        public string  accountXml { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Special_id { get; set; }
    }
```

---

Then :

```
   public List<Account> GetAccountsAsXmlList(string filePath)
   {
     XmlDocument x = new XmlDocument();

     x.Load(filePath);
     List<Account> result = new List<Account>();
     XmlNode currentNode;
     foreach (var accountNode in x.LastChild.FirstChild.ChildNodes)
     {
         currentNode = accountNode as XmlNode;
         result.Add(new Account
         {
             accountXml = currentNode.InnerXml,
             Id = currentNode.Attributes["id"].Value,
             Special_id = currentNode.Attributes["special_id"].Value,
         });
     }
      return result;
 }
```

Comment: Is there a way I can get the id and specal_id in a seperate string?

Answer (score 6):

You'll have to use `Descendants` instead of `Elements`:

```
List<string> list = doc.Root.Descendants("account").Descendants()
                   .Select(element => element.Value)
                   .ToList();
```

`Elements` only returns child elements of the element (in case of the root element this means `<main>`).
`Descendants` returns the entire tree inside the element.

**Also**: You'll have to fix the tag `<motto>Hello Everyone>` to `<motto>Hello Everyone</motto>`

Answer (score 2):

Use XPath to get the `account` element first:

```
using System.Xml.XPath;    

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

foreach(var account in doc.XPathSelectElements("accountlist/main/account")){
        List<string> list = account.Descendants()
                       .Select(element => element.Value)
                       .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication37
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" +
                "<accountlist>" +
                  "<main>" +
                    "<account id=\"1\" special_id=\"4923959\">" +
                      "<username>Adam</username>" +
                      "<motto>" +
                        "Hello Everyone>" +
                        "<money>1004</money>" +
                        "<friends>394</friends>" +
                        "<rareid>9</rareid>" +
                        "<mission>10</mission>" +
                      "</motto>" +
                      "</account>" +
                  "</main>" +
                "</accountlist>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);

            var results = doc.Descendants("accountlist").Select(x => new {
                id = x.Element("main").Element("account").Attribute("id").Value,
                special_id = x.Element("main").Element("account").Attribute("special_id").Value,
                username = x.Element("main").Element("account").Element("username").Value,
                motto = x.Element("main").Element("account").Element("motto").FirstNode.ToString(),
                money = x.Element("main").Element("account").Element("motto").Element("money").Value,
                friends = x.Element("main").Element("account").Element("motto").Element("friends").Value,
                rareid = x.Element("main").Element("account").Element("motto").Element("rareid").Value,
                mission = x.Element("main").Element("account").Element("motto").Element("mission").Value,
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```