# Read nodes of a xml file in C#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview

How can I read the following xml file into a List:

> Partial XML file (data.log)

```
<ApplicationLogEventObject>
    <EventType>Message</EventType>
    <DateStamp>10/13/2016 11:15:00 AM</DateStamp>
    <ShortDescription>N/A</ShortDescription>
    <LongDescription>Sending 'required orders' email.</LongDescription>
</ApplicationLogEventObject>
<ApplicationLogEventObject>
    <EventType>Message</EventType>
    <DateStamp>10/13/2016 11:15:10 AM</DateStamp>
    <ShortDescription>N/A</ShortDescription>
    <LongDescription>Branches Not Placed Orders - 1018</LongDescription>
</ApplicationLogEventObject>
<ApplicationLogEventObject>
    <EventType>Message</EventType>
    <DateStamp>10/13/2016 11:15:10 AM</DateStamp>
    <ShortDescription>N/A</ShortDescription>
    <LongDescription>Branches Not Placed Orders - 1019</LongDescription>
</ApplicationLogEventObject>
...
```

> And here is the data access layer (DAL):

```
public List<FLM.DataTypes.ApplicationLogEventObject> Get()
    {
        try
        {
            XmlTextReader xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(@"C:\data.log");
        List<FLM.DataTypes.ApplicationLogEventObject> recordSet = new List<ApplicationLogEventObject>();

        xmlTextReader.Read();

        while (xmlTextReader.Read())
        {
            xmlTextReader.MoveToElement();
            FLM.DataTypes.ApplicationLogEventObject record = new ApplicationLogEventObject();

            record.EventType = xmlTextReader.GetAttribute("EventType").ToString();
            record.DateStamp = Convert.ToDateTime(xmlTextReader.GetAttribute("DateStamp"));
            record.ShortDescription = xmlTextReader.GetAttribute("ShortDescription").ToString()                    
            record.LongDescription = xmlTextReader.GetAttribute("LongDescription").ToString();

            recordSet.Add(record);
        }
        return recordSet;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

> And the Data Types which will hold the child elements from the XML file:

```
public class ApplicationLogEventObject
{
    public string EventType { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateStamp { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string LongDescription { get; set; }
}
```

After I've read the child nodes into a List I would then like to return it and display it in a DataGridView.

Any help regarding this question will be much appreciated.

Comment: It looks fine, what is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619324/how-to-read-a-xml-file-and-write-into-list

Comment: Is the problem that you need to read Fragments? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.conformancelevel(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The problem is that it's not returning the data, i.e. Message, 10/13/2016 11:15:00 AM, N/A, Sending 'required orders' email. etc...

Comment: You are using GetAttribute which would get the value of an attribute not the value of the node contents. (ie. <MyNode MyAttribute="Foo">.

Comment: @Lindos Pechos So how do I go about getting the value of the node contents?

Comment: @rene Not too sure what exactly you mean by reading fragments to be totally honest.

Comment: Possibly [ReadElementContentAsString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162530(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Lindos Pechos Thanks very mcu, I'll give ReadElementContentAsString a go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your log file is not an XML document.  Since an XML document must have one and only one [root element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element), it's a series of XML documents concatenated together.  Such a series of documents can be read by [`XmlReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) by setting [`XmlReaderSettings.ConformanceLevel == ConformanceLevel.Fragment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.conformancelevel.aspx).  Having done so, you can read through the file and deserialize each root element individually using [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) as follows:

```
static List<ApplicationLogEventObject> ReadEvents(string fileName)
{
    return ReadObjects<ApplicationLogEventObject>(fileName);
}

static List<T> ReadObjects<T>(string fileName)
{
    var list = new List<T>();

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    var settings = new XmlReaderSettings { ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment };
    using (var textReader = new StreamReader(fileName))
    using (var xmlTextReader = XmlReader.Create(textReader, settings))
    {
        while (xmlTextReader.Read())
        {   // Skip whitespace
            if (xmlTextReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) 
            {
                using (var subReader = xmlTextReader.ReadSubtree())
                {
                    var logEvent = (T)serializer.Deserialize(subReader);
                    list.Add(logEvent);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return list;            
}
```

Using the following version of `ApplicationLogEventObject`:

```
public class ApplicationLogEventObject
{
    public string EventType { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("DateStamp")]
    public string DateStampString { 
        get
        {
            // Replace with culturally invariant desired formatting.
            return DateStamp.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        set
        {
            DateStamp = Convert.ToDateTime(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public DateTime DateStamp { get; set; }

    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string LongDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Sample [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8PTWxw).

Notes:

- The `<DateStamp>` element values `10/13/2016 11:15:00 AM` are not in the correct format for dates and times in XML, which is [ISO 8601](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254753/what-is-the-correct-format-to-use-for-date-time-in-an-xml-file).  Thus I introduced a surrogate `string DateStampString` property to manually handle the conversion from and to your desired format, and then marked the original `DateTime` property with [`XmlIgnore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute.aspx).
- Using [`ReadSubtree()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readsubtree.aspx) prevents the possibility of reading past the end of each root element when the XML is not indented.
- According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.aspx) for `XmlTextReader`:

  > Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, we recommend that you use the System.Xml.XmlReader class instead.

  Thus I recommend replacing use of that type with `XmlReader`.
- The child nodes of your `<ApplicationLogEventObject>` are elements not attributes, so [`XmlReader.GetAttribute()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxy2cd1w.aspx) was not an appropriate method to use to read them.
- Given that your log files are not formatting their times in ISO 8601, you should at least make sure they are formatted in a culturally invariant format so that log files can be exchanged between computers with different regional settings.  Doing your conversions using [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) ensures this.

Comment: Awesome thanks very much for the code and explanation dbc, appreciate it.

Comment: I just want to test the code out this weekend, or early next week and if it has answered my question, which looking at your code it does seem like it should, I'll definitely mark your answer as the solution to my problem ;-).