# Best way to read this xml in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, model-view-controller

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<users>
  <user id="12">
    <Nome>pedro</Nome>
    <Email>pedro.roldan@gmail.com</Email>
    <DataNascimento>1976-01-01</DataNascimento>
    <Foto>E:\Trabalho\web\12_7a639ffac9146d346372eb7598e1642f.jpg</Foto>
  </user>
  <user id="13">
    <Nome>DORA</Nome>
    <Email>dora.bilro@gmail.com</Email>
    <DataNascimento>2003-02-12</DataNascimento>
    <Foto>E:\Trabalho\web\13_135bb70e258379ee643d575bd688a692.jpg</Foto>
  </user>
  <user id="14">
    <Nome>dcdc</Nome>
    <Email>rui.moura@ff.pt</Email>
    <DataNascimento>1998-03-25</DataNascimento>
    <Foto>E:\Trabalho\web\14_7a639ffac9146d346372eb7598e1642f.jpg</Foto>
  </user>
</users>
```

Im trying to import this in asp.net mvc.

What would be the best way to read this into a c# list?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you written a DTO class yet?  What is it that you are struggling with?  Serialization?  Lists?

Comment: How should i read the xml data so that i can populate a List<User> with the data ?

Comment: Did you read the answer given at the duplicate? And the duplicates of the duplicate mentioned as comments there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<MyClass>));

using(FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite("filename"))
{
  List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();
  serializer.Serialize(stream, list);
}

using(FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("filename"))
{
  List<MyClass> dezerializedList = (List<MyClass>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

From [How to read a XML file and write into List<>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619324/how-to-read-a-xml-file-and-write-into-list#9619418)

Comment: Please do not copy paste an answer to another question. It is exactly the same as the answer of [Enyra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619324/how-to-read-a-xml-file-and-write-into-list#9619418). Instead mark the question as a duplicate.