# Cannot load internal nodes from XML file

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have a xml schema in the form of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project ref="edward" name="Edward(A)">
<desc/>
<Zones>
   <Zone ref="1" name="Zone1"/>
   <Zone ref="2" name="Zone2"/>
   <Zone ref="3" name="Zone3"/>
   <Zone ref="4" name="Zone4"/>
</Zones>
</project>
```

I am trying to extract all the Zones value using Xml to Linq (not an expert)

I tried

```
 string xmlString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("..\\..\\..\\v1.xml");

 XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
 xdoc=XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

 var ele = xdoc.Descendants("Zones")
               .Select(x => (string)x.Element("name"))
               .FirstOrDefault();
 // this is null



var result = xdoc.Element("project").Descendants("Zones").Descendants("Zone");
foreach (var item in result)
{
      Console.WriteLine(item.name); //what should be here
}
```

Comment: @JohnG The value obtained is <Zone ref=1 name="Zone1"/> I dont know how to split it. Or is there a way I can get all off them into list

Comment: Have you tried... `Console.WriteLine(item.Attribute("name").Value);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the items to a list or using a `Dictionary<int, string>` may look something like...

```
Dictionary<int, string> Zones = new Dictionary<int, string>();
foreach (var item in result) {
  int.TryParse(item.Attribute("ref").Value, out int value);
  Zones.Add(value, item.Attribute("name").Value);
  Console.WriteLine(item.Attribute("name").Value);
  Console.WriteLine(item.Attribute("ref").Value);
}
```

***Another approach using two simple Classes…***

Looking closer, I am betting using a couple of classes and the `System.Xml.Serialization;` library may make this easier. Given the XML file. One Class appears obvious… called a `Zone` object with the `int` and `string` properties. Then another Class we could call `ZoneProject`.

The `ZoneProject` Class would have three (3) properties. In this case two `string` properties called `Ref` and `Name`, and a `List<Zone>` of `Zone` objects called `Zones.` The bare minimum of these two classes may look something like…

The `Zone` Class

```
public class Zone {
  [XmlAttribute("ref")]
  public int Ref { get; set; }
  
  [XmlAttribute("name")]
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The `ZoneProject` Class

```
[XmlRoot("project")]
public class ZoneProject {
  [XmlAttribute("ref")]
  public string Ref { get; set; }
  
  [XmlAttribute("name")]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  
  [XmlArray("Zones")]
  public List<Zone> Zones { get; set; }
}
```

To help “deserialize” the XML we added additional qualifiers to help mate the XML element/attributes to the particular property of each class. The `XmlRoot` is the base class `ZoneProject` with the `XmlAttributes` and the collection of `Zone` objects using the `XmlArray` qualifier. This property will be a `List<Zone>` collection. The same follows for the `Zone` Class.

With this set up, we can use the `System.Xml.Serialization;` library and deserialize the XML file into a single `ZoneProject` object. Something like…

```
string filePath = @"PathToYourXML_File\file.xml";
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ZoneProject));
ZoneProject TheZoneProject;
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filePath)) {
  TheZoneProject = (ZoneProject)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
}
```

It should be noted, that the answer from [@Enyra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90745/enyra) on the SO question [How to read XML file into List<>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619324/how-to-read-xml-file-into-list) …was helpful in the answer above.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your xml file path. I think that , problem here.

```
 string xmlString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(dicorrectPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can collect you zones attributes with Linq:

```
var result = xdoc.Element("project").Descendants("Zones").Descendants("Zone");
var zonesAtributes = result.Select(x => 
    new 
    { 
        name = x.Attribute("name").Value, 
        @ref = x.Attribute("ref").Value 
    }).ToArray();
```